# Connecting a Raspberry Pi Pico W to a WPA2 Enterprise network (Eduroam)

Tags: python, wifi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico W as part of a group project and I am needing to connect it to the WiFi at my university. However I cannot figure out how to do it, I've searched online and everything has start the same thing:

```
from network import WLAN

wlan = WLAN(mode=WLAN.STA)
wlan.connect(ssid='eduroam', auth=(WLAN.WPA2_ENT, 'user', 'pass'), [identity='myidentity', ca_certs='/flash/cert/ca.pem'])
```

I have tried to run this code in hopes it would work, however due to version issues it does not seem to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.